# Creating HTML5 desktop application

Tags: html

I am new to HTML (HTML5). I want to create a desktop widget using `HTML5`. i.e., I dont want to run my application in browser. Is there any IDE to create such a thing?

Comment: You could try to pack chromium or any other opensource browser along with your html5 files.

Comment: I am not sure you are stating your question quite right so that people can help. HTML5 is a markup language for browsers (putting if very simplistically). You can create HTML5 in anything as simple as Notepad or as complex as Visual Studio (for example). The end HTML5 that an end user will view will be in some form of browser whether a native browser like Chome or IE, or a browser embedded into an app. Can you maybe consider this and flesh out your question?

Comment: I am new to HTML and quite confusing. My requirement is, I should develop an application using HTML5. The output should be in the exe or app format. When I open it, it should open like an exe but not in the browser.

Comment: Then you might want to reconsider your choice of technology as HTML5 does not turn into an .exe without a lot of additional work (such as including a browser in the exe as robnick suggests).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has come a long way and will get much better. NW.js or Electron is the answer. Other option is to have a webapp frontend and a nodejs service for native OS handling and web sockets for communication (similar to traditional client-server architecture).